# How to print two dimension array into phpexcel

Tags: phpexcel

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [orderId] => 3
            [qty] => 200
            [dailyUsedQty] => 10
            [balQty] => 190
            [createdDate] => 2014-06-27
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [orderId] => 3
            [qty] => 200
            [dailyUsedQty] => 20
            [balQty] => 170
            [createdDate] => 2014-06-27
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [orderId] => 3
            [qty] => 200
            [dailyUsedQty] => 50
            [balQty] => 120
            [createdDate] => 2014-06-27
        )

)
```

This is my array how can I write this array into `phpexcel`, I m new in php and php excel.

Answer (score 0):

Use the worksheet's fromArray() method

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->fromArray($myArray);
```